# How do I check out a certain revision with Git?

Tags: git

From time to time I want to do this simple thing using Git:

I have a git repository with several commits.

Now how do I checkout all directories and files of a particular commit ?

Should I clone the repo locally and then do a  git checkout for that particular commit ?

Is there a simpler command which just checks out all the files and directories of a particular commit to a local directory ? I'm just going to use those files and I'm not going to change them etc, So I do not need to create a local repo just for checking out a few files and viewing them. Correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for `git archive`. Maybe something like this:

```
 $ git archive --format=tar --prefix=my-tag-or-commit-id/ my-tag-or-commit-id | (cd /path/to/repo/checkout && tar xf -)
```

Check `git help archive` for other options and examples. You can use remote branch names for  as well.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for. I just need to download a bunch of files from a repository for a particular commit and git archive seems to do exactly that !

Comment: +1. I didn't read your last paragraph. This is what you need. You can use tags to remember the commits which you archived from just in case you need to keep track.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set your repo to the state (i.e. commit) of `fa4ef34`, use [`git checkout`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html):

```
git checkout fa4ef34
```

This will bring your working copy to the state of `fa4ef34`.

If you want to check out `master` again, do a

```
git checkout master
```

---

However, if you're interested in a certain commit of a **remote** repo, you have to do it a bit different.

First, initialize a local repo:

```
git init myrepo
cd myrepo
```

Now, you are in your freshly created local repo. To get hands on the commits of a remote repo (for example the Bluetooth packet analyzer), you have to do the following:

```
git remote add bluez_hcidump git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez-hcidump.git
git fetch bluez_hcidump
```

Now, your repo knows everything about the `bluez_hcidump` repo. If you want to access commit `fa4ef34` that belongs to that repo, do the steps described at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: But can you do this without first doing a `git clone remoterepo`?

Comment: @tripleee: No, you always have to clone the repo. Git does not have the concept of "not having a repository on your machine". To do anything meaningful you have to have the repo locally. (unless of course you want the action to be performed on the remote computer/repo)

Answer (score 1):

When you have a repository, you have all the revisions of all the files available to you. First you find the commit you're interested in using `git log`. Then once you find out [some way of referring to the commmit](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) you're interested in, you can cut a branch starting from that commit using `git branch branch_name <the commit you're interested in>`. Now you'll have a local branch (called `branch_name` at that commit and you can `git checkout branch_name` to see what things looked like at that time.